# Azure function firing httpclient.postasync multiple times within http trigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Azure function with a http trigger to listen for an incoming web post requests with a JSON payload.
When the trigger receives a request I want to parse the json data and call an external restapi based on some of the json data.

For some reason the web trigger is posting to the external restapi 5 times.  When I remove the external restapi code it fires only once as i have picked up with the streaming log info.

Could someone tell me what may be the issue or an alternate way to achieve the same functionality?

here is httptrigger c# code

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class PostData
{
public string name { get;set; }    
}

// The string caller was added to the function parameters to get the caller from the URL.
// The ICollector<string> outQueue was added to the function parameters to get access to the output queue.
public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, string caller, 
ICollector<string> outQueue, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info($"Webhook was triggered!");

// The JSON payload is found in the request
string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

// Create a dynamic JSON output, enveloping the payload with 
// The caller, a timestamp, and the payload itself
dynamic outData = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
outData.caller = caller;
outData.timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
outData.payload = data;

// Add the JSON as a string to the output queue
outQueue.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outData));     

//Post to restapi
log.Info("starting post routine ID:" + data.incident + " Incident: " + data.service);
StringContent mv_stringContent = new StringContent("{ \"name\": \"" + data.service + " issue!" + "\", \"message\": \"" + "Incident: " + data.incident + ": " + data.service + "\", \"visible\": \"1\", \"status\": \"2\", \"notify\": \"true\" }", UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", "supersecret");
HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client.PostAsync("https://testing.mysite.com/api/v1/incidents", mv_stringContent);
var responseString = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
log.Info("finsihed post rotuine");    

// Return status 200 OK to the calling system..
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
{
   caller = $"{caller}",
    status = "OK",
    test = ""
});
}
```

Comment: How long is it taking for your external POST request to complete? It's possible that if it is delayed long enough, the webhook sender you be retrying its POST request. Expected response time to a webhook request can vary a lot.